# Unable to build project in Intellij using Build > Build Project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am seeing a strange issue for one of my maven project in IntelliJ i.e. when I try to execute Build > Build Project (from menu) nothing happens i.e. IntelliJ does not build project.

Also, I tried to run / debug configuration for a cucumber file even that did not work.

I am able to use options like analyze code, sonarlint or run my tests using mvn command line. Also, build / run debug configuration works fine for other projects but not one specific project.

I was wondering if anyone else has seen this issue earlier?

Comment: Did you import the project as a Maven one?

Comment: Thanks Eugen. I am able to execute mvn commands (mvn clean, compile, install, etc) and it seems to work fine from command line as well as maven menu however, it's the build option using the menu which does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to IntelliJ 2018.3 and it seems to have resolved the problem, I am now able to build the projects successfully.

I am marking this as an answer as it did solve the initial problem but to be honest really not sure what actually resolved the problem as the release notes for 2018.3 does not explicitly says anything about the problem (moreover I actually imported settings from IntelliJ 2017.X version).